# How to link a servlet as a directory+servlet Web.xml?

Tags: servlets, web.xml

Basically I have a servlet say: `gubis`.

To be precise: I need my `gubis` servlet be accessed as `servs/gubis`

The goal I want to reach is that if I made the request as `localhost:8080/EclipsePro/servs/gubis` the request should be redirected to `localhost:8080/EclipsePro/gubis`

I tried:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servs/gubis</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>duck.reg.pack.gubis</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servs/gubis</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/gubis</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But it didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

If you need gubis servlet be accessed as servs/gubis

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>gubis</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>duck.reg.pack.gubis</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>gubis</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>servs/gubis</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The goal I want to reach is that if I made the request as localhost:8080/EclipsePro/servs/gubis the request should be redirected to localhost:8080/EclipsePro/gubis

You can use url-rewriting to achieve the above.

Comment: Ahh, That makes my apache server never start and pops the error saying `Server Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost failed to start.`